# Sharing codeigniter models,config, and libraries with multiple apps

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am expanding a site built with codeigniter, its to have an api and mobile version.
I intended to seperate the api and mobile site from the main site using sub domains.

- test.com
- api.test.com
- m.test.com

There are many models,and libraries already written for the main site which is to be used by the site,api, and mobile, and i do not want to replicate them.
Am working with codeigniter 2.1.0.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I would go further and attempt to keep it all within the same instance of codeigniter. You should, with a little hackery, be able to treat different subdomains as if they are just different URLs.

Comment: See my question here about how to do different things with subdomains http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649858/codeigniter-how-to-route-controller-based-on-whether-a-subdomain-exists-or-not.

Comment: @Catfish do the urls maintain the original state, i.e for example does api.test.com remain api.test.com in the url bar

Comment: yes it does. You have to set the base_url() using pretty much the same method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into using [Application Packages](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html).  You could add your main site `application/` folder to your API and mobile sites as an application package.  CodeIgniter will then fall back to looking into your main site `application/` folder when you attempt to load resources.

Using this method you could use the same models, helpers, and libraries between all three of your applications but write custom controllers and views for your API and mobile sites.

**Edit (1/12/2012):** For anyone interested, I wrote a blog post about this question discussing the usage of application packages.  The post can be read [here](http://eric-famiglietti.com/2012/01/11/get-a-handle-on-application-packages/).

Comment: But does this approach not incur additional page loading time?

Comment: CodeIgniter prepends the application path to the list of paths to check when loading resources.  The increase in time would be negligible and not noticeable by the user.

Comment: Seems like a good solution, but my controllers can't find the view files in my standard application/views directory, event though I passed in `false` with `add_package_path()`. Do you know why this might be?